# Sending message to SQS via PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I am attempting to send a message to SQS and I have followed instructions laid here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html

However, when I follow these I do not get anything, not even an error message. The code is as follows:

```
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient; 
$credentials = new Credentials('IAM account key', 'IAM secret key')
    $sqsClient = new SqsClient([
        'version' => '2012-11-05',
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'region' => 'eu-north-1',
  ]);

//Debug values, these would later be filled from database
$params = [
    'DelaySeconds' => 10,
    'MessageAttributes' => [
        "SocialSecurityCode" => [
            'DataType' => "String",
            'StringValue' => "111111-1"
        ],
        "Name" => [
            'DataType' => "String",
            'StringValue' => "Teemu Testaaja"
        ],
        "PeriodStart" => [
            'DataType' => "String",
            'StringValue' => "1-1-2019"
        ],
        "PeriodEnd" => [
            'DataType' => "String",
            'StringValue' => "31-1-2019"
        ],
        "EventDate" => [
            'DataType' => "String",
            'StringValue' => "12-1-2019"
        ],
        "Code" => [
            'DataType' => "Number",
            'StringValue' => "12"
        ],
        "Amount" => [
            'DataType' => "Number",
            'StringValue' => "7.5"
        ]
    ],
    'MessageBody' => "Test message",
    'QueueUrl' => 'sqs-url from the console'
];

try {
    print("Sending message");
    $result = $sqsClient->sendMessage($params);
    print("Message send");
    var_dump($result);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    print("ERROR!");
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Yet, only thing I get out is "Sending message". What am I doing wrong here? I have an IAM account set up with ability to send and read messages from the queu.

I tried to look at the queu to see if messages did pass and there was something else, but there are no items in the queu and there is currently nothing reading it.

Code is hosted on Amazon AWS server.

UPDATE

As of now, messages are correctly passed to the queu, but code does not proceed from sendMessages part forward.

Comment: Have you made sure you can [see any and all errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)?

Comment: If you check the CloudWatch metrics for this SQS queue do you see anything at all?

Comment: Where are you executing this? On your local workstation, or on some ec2 instance in a vpc?

Comment: @Phil As far as I know. I do not have full access to the system.

Comment: @mokugo-devops what i should be looking for in CloudWatch? I can see the SQS service and it shows now errors.

Comment: @Marcin At the AWS server.

Comment: Seems to me its timing out if it hangs on `$sqsClient->sendMessage($params);`. Can you confirm that you have internet access or can manually send messages to the sqs using AWS CLI?

Comment: @Marcin Confirmed that I can send message using AWS CLI.

Comment: Ok, so queue is reachable. Using aws cli, have you used the same `$credentials` as in the code? As a side note, better to use instance roles for access to sqs, rather then hardcoding keys in the code.

Comment: Hi @Mandemon just connect to CloudWatch and see if there are any metrics for your SQS queue at all

Comment: Hi, did you dump `$params` to check the content? Is content looks ok (QueueUrl ...)?

Comment: @Marcin agreed on using instance roles, but these are for debugging purposes until everything works. As far as I can see, credentials are the same

Comment: So it seems that there is something wrong with the php code. Just by looking at it I don't know at present what can be wrong. Maybe have to enable these extra errors, which @Phil mentioned, and look for some error messages.

Comment: @qdequippe Yes, it matches what is seen

Comment: @Marcin I request the changed made to allow full error reporting. Still nothing.

Comment: @Phil  I request the changed made to allow full error reporting. Still nothing

Comment: Update: Message are now passing through(SQS shows new messages appearing), but code still stops on the sendMessage. I updated code to form seen in original post now to confirm that this.

Comment: So what was wrong that now it sends messages?

Comment: @Marcin Bugger if I know, it now sends the messages correctly. I am tempted to say Wizard Did It to be honest. This started after .htaccess was changed to allow larger error reporting as per Phils link.

However, the code still seems to hang up on sendMessage part, not proceeding from there.

Comment: At least there is some progress.